# Oracle SQL: SQL query producing 4 times the results and data wont order correctly

Tags: sql, database, oracle, microsoft-query

### I have the following query:

```
Select DISTINCT * From
(
SELECT "WORK_CENTER"."EQNO" AS E1,
"WORK_CENTER"."CNTR_TYPE",
"WORK_CENTER"."CNTR_DESC",
"WORK_CENTER"."MFGCELL",
"WORK_CENTER"."MFG_TYPE",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER1",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER2",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER3",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER4",
"WORK_CENTER"."CUSER5",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER1",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER2",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER3",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER4",
"WORK_CENTER"."NUSER5",
"UD_DATA"."CUSER"
FROM   "IQMS"."UD_DATA" "UD_DATA" 
 FULL OUTER JOIN "IQMS"."WORK_CENTER" "WORK_CENTER" ON  "UD_DATA"."PARENT_ID"="WORK_CENTER"."ID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "IQMS"."UD_COLS" "UD_COLS" ON "UD_DATA"."UD_COLS_ID" = "UD_COLS"."ID" 
WHERE  "WORK_CENTER"."MFG_TYPE"='INJECTION' AND "UD_COLS"."ID"='16'),

(SELECT 
"WORK_CENTER"."EQNO" AS E2,
"UD_DATA"."CUSER" AS "U2"
FROM   "IQMS"."UD_DATA" "UD_DATA" 
FULL OUTER JOIN "IQMS"."WORK_CENTER" "WORK_CENTER" ON "UD_DATA"."PARENT_ID"="WORK_CENTER"."ID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "IQMS"."UD_COLS" "UD_COLS" ON "UD_DATA"."UD_COLS_ID" = "UD_COLS"."ID" 
WHERE "UD_COLS"."ID"='17') ORDER BY E1,E2
```

E2 is something I tried to use to organise the data, I don't want this column to show.
This is the desired result(not showing blank columns and apologies for badly formatted table):

```
EQNO | CNTR_TYPE | CNTR_DESC | MFGCELL | MFG_TYPE | CUSER | U2

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test1

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test2

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test3

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test4
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
EQNO | CNTR_TYPE | CNTR_DESC | MFGCELL | MFG_TYPE | CUSER | U2 | E2

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test1 | 001

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test2 | 002

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test3 | 003

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test4 | 005

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test1 | 001

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test2 | 002

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test3 | 003

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test4 | 005

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test1 | 001

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test2 | 002

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test3 | 003

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test4 | 005

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test1 | 001 

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test2 | 002

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test3 | 003

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test4 | 005
```

Union doesn't really work as it just puts the two columns "CUSER" and "CUSER AS U2" together since they are the same column really.

What can I do to fix this and/or is there something I'm doing very wrong?(I guess that would be most likely)

Even just being told what to look at would be extremely helpful. I've been working on this for a couple of days and not making much progress.

Comment: I got a comment that that this may be due to the tables being a cross product? I did not realise thats what was happening. From quick googling it looks like it gets every combination it seems. I'll look into this. Thanks to the person who said!

Answer (score 0):

The crossproduct of those two selects is created. The results are handled like independent tables. I deleted because I could not elaborate more.
If it was helpfull, great.