# Oracle SQL: Subqueries to query same column twice under different condition from mulitple tables

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, microsoft-query

This question kind of links to [my previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275914/oracle-sql-sql-query-producing-4-times-the-results-and-data-wont-order-correctl)

I'm trying to break it down a little to just get the last two columns organized and without duplicates.

I'm attempting to do something similar to the top rated solution on [this site.](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/663441/Select-same-coulmn-twice-from-a-table-with-two-dif)

I'm using excels query builder to try and do this as I am not that familiar beyond simple basics of sql and databases.

The statement is currently:

```
SELECT WORK_CENTER.EQNO,
(
SELECT
UD_DATA.CUSER AS U1
FROM UD_DATA
FULL OUTER JOIN 
WORK_CENTER 
ON UD_DATA.PARENT_ID = WORK_CENTER.ID 
LEFT JOIN 
UD_COLS 
ON UD_DATA.UD_COLS_ID = UD_COLS.ID
WHERE UD_COLS.ID='16'
),
(
SELECT
UD_DATA.CUSER AS U2
FROM UD_DATA
FULL OUTER JOIN WORK_CENTER ON UD_DATA.PARENT_ID = WORK_CENTER.ID 
LEFT JOIN UD_COLS ON UD_DATA.UD_COLS_ID = UD_COLS.ID
WHERE UD_COLS.ID='17'
)

FROM   
IQMS.UD_DATA UD_DATA
FULL OUTER JOIN 
IQMS.WORK_CENTER WORK_CENTER 
ON WORK_CENTER.ID=UD_DATA.PARENT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
IQMS.UD_COLS UD_COLS 
ON 
UD_DATA.UD_COLS_ID = UD_COLS.ID 
ORDER BY WORK_CENTER.EQNO
```

Desired Result:

```
EQNO | U1   | U2
-----+------+------
001  | 1000 | test1
002  | 2000 | test2
003  | 3000 | test3
004  | 4000 | test4
```

But I'm currently getting

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   **Thanks to Pattrick Bacon. Pointed out my overlooking having LEFT JOIN JOIN**

In the linked question it was suggested that the cause of the wrong output was due to the two tables being cross joined, I tried to get an understanding of it online and I was unable to really see a solution around it except for trying this.

I haven't changed too much of the subqueries themselves but I'm obviously doing something wrong. would anyone be able to help?

> Someone asked for more examples

From my linked question:

This is the desired result(not showing blank columns and apologies for badly formatted table):

```
EQNO | CNTR_TYPE | CNTR_DESC | MFGCELL | MFG_TYPE | CUSER | U2

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test1

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test2

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test3

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test4
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
EQNO | CNTR_TYPE | CNTR_DESC | MFGCELL | MFG_TYPE | CUSER | U2 | E2

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test1 | 001

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test2 | 002

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test3 | 003

001 | 110T-40MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 110-430 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 1000 | test4 | 005

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test1 | 001

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test2 | 002

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test3 | 003

002 | 150T-25MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-320 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 2000 | test4 | 005

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test1 | 001

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test2 | 002

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test3 | 003

003 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG SYSTEM 150-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 3000 | test4 | 005

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test1 | 001 

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test2 | 002

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test3 | 003

005 | 150T-45MM | DEMAG EXTRA  500-610 | MOLDING | INJECTION | 4000 | test4 | 005
```

Union doesn't really work as it just puts the two columns "CUSER" and "CUSER AS U2" together since they are the same column really.

> Adding more sample data

Here's a bit from the UD_DATA table

```
ID     | UD_COLS_ID|PARENT_ID|CUSER
-------+-----------+---------+------
12312  | 16        | 5210    | 1000
12313  | 17        | 5210    | test1
12314  | 16        | 5212    | 2000
12315  | 17        | 5212    | test2
12316  | 16        | 5213    | 3000
12317  | 17        | 5213    | test4
12318  | 16        | 5214    | 4000
12319  | 17        | 5214    | test4
```

My main issue is just displaying the date from the CUSER column as

```
      |COL1 | COL2|
      +-----+-----+
      | 1000|test1|
      | 2000|test2|
      | 3000|test3|
      | 4000|test4|
```

But from the linked question I got something like:

```
      |COL1 | COL2|
      +-----+-----+
      | 1000|test1|
      | 1000|test2|
      | 1000|test3|
      | 1000|test4|
      | 2000|test1|
      | 2000|test2|
      | 2000|test3|
      | 2000|test4|
      | 3000|test1|
      | 3000|test2|
      | 3000|test3|
      | 3000|test4|
```

This is what I've been struggling with trying to fix

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? You should provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Sorry. I'll do that now. It's mostly in the linked question. I don't know if the problem persists if this works though. I'm currently trying to display two columns which are actually from the same column, but filtered by different conditions. But instead of 4 rows I get 16

Comment: It would really help if you could provide sample data from your tables that generates the expected output you're after, along with the logic for which values get chosen.

Comment: Ok. If you mean data from each table I'll do that now

Comment: Are lines 9 and 19 with the typo,  `LEFT JOIN JOIN `, a typo in your post or a typo in your select statement?

Comment: Syntactically, you have two outer join sub-queries acting as scalar queries in your select clause at lines 2 to 13 and lines 14 to 21. I think your intentions are to have these sub-queries in your  `from` clause.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the JOIN JOIN out. I had not noticed I did that. Fixing it now. Will put up sample data in a bit. Unable to post more than 2 links/images until I have reputation of 10 I just discovered

Comment: In regards to having the subqueries in the 'FROM' clause I tried something like that in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually after a PIVOT; no need for the joins, etc.

E.g.:

```
WITH ud_data AS (SELECT 12312 id, 16 ud_cols_id, 5210 parent_id, '1000' cuser FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 12313 id, 17 ud_cols_id, 5210 parent_id, 'test1' cuser FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 12314 id, 16 ud_cols_id, 5212 parent_id, '2000' cuser FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 12315 id, 17 ud_cols_id, 5212 parent_id, 'test2' cuser FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 12316 id, 16 ud_cols_id, 5213 parent_id, '3000' cuser FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 12317 id, 17 ud_cols_id, 5213 parent_id, 'test3' cuser FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 12318 id, 16 ud_cols_id, 5214 parent_id, '4000' cuser FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 12319 id, 17 ud_cols_id, 5214 parent_id, 'test4' cuser FROM dual)
SELECT parent_id,
       col1,
       col2
FROM   (SELECT parent_id,
               ud_cols_id,
               cuser
        FROM   ud_data)
PIVOT (max(cuser) FOR (ud_cols_id) IN (16 AS col1, 17 AS col2))
ORDER BY parent_id;

 PARENT_ID COL1  COL2
---------- ----- -----
      5210 1000  test1
      5212 2000  test2
      5213 3000  test3
      5214 4000  test4
```

Comment: Thanks! This could really help. The only issue I have is that another 56 could be added to UD_DATA, so things could get messy, but this definitely helps. Thanks again

Comment: Why not just extract the raw data from the table and use excel to pivot the data as needed on ud_cols_ID?  excel supports dynamic pivot whereas without dynamicSQL, you can't have a dynamic columns in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will look at doing that and try it now.

Comment: But would that involve using power pivot? That seems to show in most google searches

Comment: Excel supports pivot table functionality. This doesn't seem like a "power pivot"